# Check UserID exists in Active Directory using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, userid

How can we check whether the USERID exists in Active Directory or not.

I have LDAP String and UserID, can I find whether that UserID exists in Active Directory or not.  I am using this for ASP.NET Web Application (.NET 3.5)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can do something along the lines of (replacing domain with the domain you're authenticating against or removing the parameter altogether):

```
public bool DoesUserExist(string userName)
{
    using (var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAIN"))
    {
        using (var foundUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName))
        {
            return foundUser != null;
        }
    }
}
```

To achieve checking for if a user exists.  This comes from the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace and assembly.

You can find more information at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx

You may want to check more into PrincipalContext as it has interesting methods for authenticating user credentials and such.

Comment: +1 What I would do, only better explained.  Also, you can omit the doamin name to use the local domain - handy if you've only got the one domain and don't need to know its name.

Comment: Thanks it helped.. the new namespace System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement helped..!! Well I am little bit confised at second Parameter "DOMAIN" ..? do we need to give it or not if we give is it Active Directory's Domain Name ?...

Comment: You can delete that parameter if you want to connect to the system's default domain.  Otherwise you'll need to specify the domain you're wanting to connect to.

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers if they're what you're looking for. :)

Answer (score 8):

I would use the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace.

```
string UserID = "grhm";
bool userExists = false;

using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, UserID))
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            userExists = true;
            user.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344891.aspx for more info

Comment: Thank You it worked, yeah the new namespace. System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagment made very easy...

Comment: I see in some examples there is another parameter "DOMAIN" for the PrincipleContext... Do we need to use it or not ?..

Comment: You can use other parameters to specify the domain you want to contect to - as in the other answer.  I see Joshua has explained this already above...

Comment: You declare `user`, but I never see `usr` declared.  Should those be the same variable?

Comment: @BrianJ: Yep, they should be.  Edited to fix it.

Comment: You don't need to dispose(), as the Using() does that for you.

Comment: Also this wouldn't work if it ran from IIS, as IIS_USER or what ever account is running from the web service will need to be added into AD as well and given high priveleges to run AD methods.