# How to check if user is a Domain User or Local User?

Tags: windows, security, winapi

I want to be able to check if the user running the current thread is:

- a Domain User
- a Local User of the machine

There are some cavaets:

- i do not know (or care) if the machine is domain joined
- because the domain of the logged in user could be from a different from the machine domain
- and because the domain of the user that the process is running as could from the logged in user or machine domains
- and because the domain of the user that the thread is running as could be from the process, logged in or machine domains

In other words, i want:

```
public static Boolean IsLocalUser()
{
   //code here
}
```

### Research Effort

What follows is extraneous bonus information. It adds nothing to the question, but is here solely to make the question longer.

**Check if machine is domain joined using `NetGetJoinInformation`**

I can use [`NetGetJoinInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to check if the local machine is joined to a domain:

```
NetGetJoinInformation(null, ref domain, ref joinStatus);
```

Returns:

- NetSetupUnknownStatus: The status is unknown.
- NetSetupUnjoined: The computer is not joined.
- NetSetupWorkgroupName: The computer is joined to a workgroup.

  - `domain` contains name of workgroup (e.g. `WORKGROUP`)
- NetSetupDomainName: The computer is joined to a domain.

  - `domain` contains the legacy NetBIOS name of the domain (e.g. `STACKOVERFLOW`)

**Check if machine is domain joined using `DsRoleGetPrimaryDomainInformation`**

I can use [`DsRoleGetPrimaryDomainInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to check if the local machine is joined to a domain:

```
DsRoleGetPrimaryDomainInformation(null, 
      DsRolePrimaryDomainInfoBasic, 
      DSROLE_PRIMARY_DOMAIN_INFO_BASIC);
```

Returns a `DSROLE_PRIMARY_DOMAIN_INFO_BASIC` structure:

- `MachineRole`

  - `DsRole_RoleStandaloneWorkstation`: the machine is not domain joined
  - `DsRole_RoleStandaloneServer`: the machine is not domain joined
  - `DsRole_RoleMemberWorkstation`: the machine **is** domain joined
  - `DsRole_RoleMemberServer`: the machine **is** domain joined
  - `DsRole_RoleBackupDomainController`: the machine **is** domain joined
  - `DsRole_RolePrimaryDomainController`: the machine **is** domain joined
- `DomainNameDns`: returns the DNS Domain name (e.g. `stackoverflow.com`) *(optional)*
- `DomainNameFlat`: returns the legacy NetBIOS domain name (e.g. `STACKOVERFLOW`)

But, again, telling me name name of the domain that the machine is joined to doesn't help when the user is not a domain user, or the user is from a different domain

**Getting the name of the current user using `GetUserName`**

Windows does provide a [`GetUserName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function:

```
GetUserName(buffer, Length(buffer));
```

returns the name of the user, e.g. `lsimpson`

**Getting the name of the current user using `GetUserNameEx`**

Windows does provide a `GetUserNameEx` function, that allows you to return the username in different formats:

- **NameUnknown**: *(nothing)*
- **NameFullyQualifiedDN**: `CN=John Smith,OU=Stackoverflow  Users,DC=stackoverflow,DC=com`
- **NameSamCompatible**: `STACKOVERFLOW\jsmith`
- **NameDisplay**: `John`
- **NameUniqueId**: `{C1AF1DE6-363D-42A7-BB0D-9D1EDDC44B81}`
- **NameCanonical**: `stackoverflow.com/Stackoverfow Users/John Smith`
- **NameUserPrincipal**: `jsmith@stackoverflow.com`
- **NameCanonicalEx**: `stackoverflow.com/Stackoverflow Users/John Smith`
- **NameServicePrincipal**: *(nothing)*
- **NameDnsDomain**: `STACKOVERFLOW.COM\jsmith`

also

- **NameUnknown**:
- **NameFullyQualifiedDN**:
- **NameSamCompatible**: `HYDROGEN\john`
- **NameDisplay**:
- **NameUniqueId**:
- **NameCanonical**:
- **NameUserPrincipal**:
- **NameCanonicalEx**:
- **NameServicePrincipal**:
- **NameDnsDomain**:

**KB11154: How to retrieve current user and domain name**

Microsoft has a knowledge base article:

> [How to retrieve current user and domain names on Windows NT, Windows 2000, or Windows XP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/111544)

it involves:

- `OpenThreadToken`
- `OpenProcessToken` *(if there is no thread token)*
- `GetTokenInformation` - to get a `TOKEN_USER`
- `LookupAccountSid` - to get a username and domain name from a `TOKEN_USER`

In the end it returns:

- **username**: e.g. `jsmith`
- **domain**: e.g. `HYDROGEN`, `STACKOVERFLOW`

Comment: Downvotes without reason? Nice Stackoverflow!

Comment: Hello, I also need to implement such a function. Have you found a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Good afternoon!

I looked into some of the other solutions posted for this problem, but most of them do not take into account the caveats that you listed. Most of the relevant solutions are from the following post:

[Check if user is a Domain User or Local User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710355/check-if-user-is-a-domain-user-or-local-user)

Of these solutions, the following seems to be the most in line with what you proposed:

```
bool IsLocalUser(string accountName)
{
  var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
  return Principal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, accountName) != null;
}
```

Comment: I didn't explicitly say it, but i need the *"native"* solution - i am not inside .NET or the CLR. Also, if you follow that question ans answer three links in, it is fundamentally about checking if a user exists in Active Directory. For our purposes we will assume the user will not have permission to query active directory.