# Active Directory authentication without Login form

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

I want to authenticate my Users to Active Directory but without any login form.

I just want open my default page if user logged in to machine belongs to Active Directory.

Firstly, i used Windows Authentication but there is a requirement to authenticate user who belong to other domain as there are more than one domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you need to use the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace. Along with enabling Windows authentication, you need to write the authentication code in the `Page_Load` event of your default page. If the user is part of the required domain, authenticate him and show him the page. Otherwise, tell him that he doesn't have access.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453801/check-userid-exists-in-active-directory-using-c-sharp) should get you going.

Comment: but is it possible without windows authentication?

Comment: You need Windows authentication as this will give you the Windows username for the user, which you will use to dig into the Active Directory.